# What is in.next() doing?

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

> I am using Scanner class to take input. I am trying to get all the
>   words in a line using in.next(). I know it can be done using
>   nextLine() but i want to understand how in.next() and in.hasNext()
>   works.

```
System.out.println("What is designation");
        String desg = in.next();      
        while(in.hasNext()){
            desg+=in.next();      
        }
```

Gives out put as

```
What is designation
member technical staff\n
^Z
Hello abhishek kumarNext year you will be 22Salary is 30000.0Designation is membertechnicalstaff
```

But if i use

```
System.out.println("What is designation");
        String desg = in.next();      
        if(in.hasNext()){
            desg+=in.next();      
        }
```

It gives output as

```
What is designation
member technical staff
Hello abhishek kumarNext year you will be 22Salary is 44254.0Designation is membertechnical
```

> In the first case i am getting all the words but it keeps asking for
>   next input and i have to specify end of input using CTRL+Z. But in
>   second case i am not getting the last word(staff). Please explain.

Comment: You can ask user to press Enter twice to end the input, and use `nextLine()` to read?

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between `if` and `while`? `if` only execute once while `while` will repeat.

Comment: @AlvinWong-Thanks for realizing me.How i missed that point:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first code reads the input in a `while` loop - i.e. until it finds `in.hasNext() == false`.

The second code is using an `if` condition - it reads `in.next()` at most once (after the initial read).

Thus, the second code is not "waiting for new input" because it simply asks for `in.next()` only once, and not until input is exhausted, unlike the second code snap.

---

P.S. Note that the line `String desg = in.next();` (in the first code snap) is a bad practice for two reasons:

1. It will fail for empty input.
2. It is a code duplication with the content of the while loop.

Comment: Well, a `do ... while` loop makes no difference to doing once then using `while` loop, regarding `1. It will fail for empty input.`

Comment: Of course it doesn't, I'll delete this last comment. Thanks for the correction @AlvinWong

Answer (score 2):

its not about `in.next()` the problem is with using `if` it gets executed only once
and about `next()` it only **returns the next token**

so in 2nd case:(`if` one)
when you enter **member technical staff**
at this part : `String desg = in.next();`
only `member` is assigned to `desg`
and after it enters `if` it checks for the next token (which is **technical**) and concatenates it with the previous string `desg+=in.next()`
so now `desg` becomes `membertechnical`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn more details about a class in API, javadoc is best source. Here is [javadoc for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29).

```
public String next()
```

> Finds and returns the next complete token from this scanner. A complete token is preceded and followed by input that matches the delimiter pattern. This method may block while waiting for input to scan, even if a previous invocation of hasNext() returned true.

Comment: Also note that the default delimiter is `\s+`